# Microservices communication model

Tags: rest, architecture, microservices, messaging

Consider microservices architecture, where you need to expose functionality to manage simple configuration shared with different microservices. Configuration is not changing often, but still, I would like to see changes whenever I ask for any value.
Using REST microservice seems easy, but it is adding latency.
Alternative could be RPC over messaging (i.e. RabbitMQ), but interface becomes more complicated.

What communication are you using for internal, simple services and what are pros and cons?
Any examples?

I tried with REST API, but it means a lot of "slow" requests, which add a latency to overall requests.

Comment: Does millisecond latency *actually* matter to your application?

Comment: It does not matter for single request, but configuration items are read quite often, which would affect every request to the system. 
I have an impression, that in that case, REST is not the best choice.

Comment: 10 ms latency means 100 per second which is not very performant.

Comment: If you have 10+ microservices, which need to be used for each request, they would sum to 100 ms, which can impact performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that using RESTful APIs with some judicious implementation of cache-control headers actually works fairly well for this use case.  The biggest challenge is ensuring that the HTTP client underneath your REST client actually respects the things.

It's fairly easy to implement, fits nicely into HTTP, and generally scales really well.  It gives control to the client to decide if they want to respect the caching suggestions, allows server to optimize if it "knows" the configs haven't change (304 Not modified) to optimize if the client wants to ask for new versions.

You don't have to get into anything too complicated from a cache-invalidation, and you can leverage things like edge caching to further accelerate things in interesting ways.

Answer (score 0):

The question to ask is ultimately the extent to which it is a requirement that a change to the configuration immediately affects everything.

If that's actually a requirement, then we're talking about strong consistency which implies some combination of:

- all other processing must be effectively executed one-at-a-time against the (there can only ultimately be one: if there's multiple, then they will be affected at different times) component against which the change is made
- all other processing must stop for the duration of time that it takes to propagate the change to all components

(these can be combined: you can have multiple instances depend on the configuration and stop for as long as it takes to update those and then you can execute things in parallel... an example of this is making it static configuration in the dependent services and taking them all down to update the configuration: if these updates are sufficiently rare, you can fit them into your error/downtime budget)

Needless to say, there's a (likely surprisingly small) consistency budget you're dealing with.

If you don't actually need strong absolute consistency like I've described (and the set of problems which actually need it is perhaps surprisingly small: anything to do with money for instance doesn't actually need strong consistency because it's only money), then it's a question of how much inconsistency is acceptable (typically you'll quantify this with some sort of bounded staleness and a liveness guarantee that you don't go back in time (unless there's a really good reason to go back in time...)).  At this point, we've established that you want eventual consistency, we're just haggling over "how eventual?".

For this, propagating the configuration changes via durable publish-subscribe log (Kafka being the exemplar of this approach) is probably the place to start.  Components subscribe to this log and update local state as it changes (and probably store the log position and the last value in some local store to prevent inadvertently going backward in time when they initially read the log).  Then you can distribute the configuration so that it's in local memory of the subscribers, though during an update, there will be a window where different subscribers will have different views of that configuration.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of solutions exist to externalize microservice configuration to a central location depending on what frameworks/programming languages you used to build your services. If it happened you would be using Spring, take a look at [Spring Cloud Config](https://Do%20you%20want%20to%20share%20the%20configuration%20of%20the%20N%20microservices%20in%20a%20central%20place?). Off course Eureka is not the only solution tailored for this purpose.